# Parse Push Notifications on Android appearing twice, not appearing at all on iOS

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, push-notification, push

I've found a few posts relating to this issue but they all refer to using custom BroadcastReceiver.

The app I'm working on has been built without using a custom BroadcastReceiver and simply using PushQuery to send the notification but the notification is always being shown twice.

Here's the Manifest section :

```
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

        <category android:name="com.myapp.myapp" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Here's the method that's responsible for sending the notifications:

```
public void sendNotificationToUser(ParseUser friend, String message){
    MainUtils.log("Send push notification to " + friend.getString(ParseConstants.FIELD_FULLNAME));

    // Parse Installation
    ParseInstallation parseInstallation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
    ParseQuery pushQuery = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
    pushQuery.whereNotEqualTo("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
    pushQuery.whereEqualTo("user", friend);

    ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
    push.setQuery(pushQuery);
    push.setMessage(message);

    push.sendInBackground(new SendCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if(e != null){
                log(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Everything works fine except for:

Problem 1: the notification arriving twice. 
Problem 2: no notifications arriving at all on iOS.

Given that there is no custom BroadcastReceiver in use I can't apply any of the answers I've found to solve problem 1. Is there any extra parameter required to ensure that the messages are also sent to iOS devices (problem 2)?

Thanks in advance for any help...

Comment: Sorry I know this isn't an answer but I can't comment until I have 50 rep. You do know that Parse is shutting down in January right?

Comment: Yes Andrew, we know. We'll be using Parse Server by then.

Comment: are you 100% sure that the query matches just one row in the Installation class? you can add `pushQuery.limit = 1`. If it doesnt arrive in IOS i would say it is because you used wrong certificate, wrong Provisioning profile, misconfigured the iOS app...

Comment: @MazelTov I'm not 100% sure but adding `pushQuery.setLimit(1)` made no difference. Re. iOS: the iOS developer had not sent Parse up correctly so this will likely work once he has!

Still need to solve the double notification issue... anybody?

Comment: Are you aure you are not running the cloud code function twice?  In the dashboard you can try to send push to the device you want and you will see if it works properly... For android with parse it sometimes send the push immediatly to the device but mostly it took around half hour to deliver it...

Comment: @MazelTov I tried that. The pushQuery is being issued once only. When I send a test push to the device from the dashboard it also arrives twice. Most confusing!